# How to put results of subprocess in a variable

Tags: python, subprocess

I can retrieve my data only by using cURL, I think subprocess is the easier way to do it but I cannot put the data in a variable.

For example like this

```
data = subprocess.call('curl "URL" -X GET', shell=True)
```

Is there any easy way to do this via python?

Comment: "I can retrieve my data only by using cURL" => err, why so ? What prevents you from using some Python package ? (either from the stdlib or something higher level like http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) ?

Comment: What's the problem with using the [python bindings for libcurl](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/) and saving yourself a lot of headaches (including error handling problems)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to do this with subprocess and want the result of the call, then you are looking for `check_output`:

```
data = subprocess.check_output(["curl", URL])
```

However, I suggest you use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library in Python for what you are doing. Full of features that will make your life easier.

Here is a simple example on using requests:

Make sure you have installed requests first. It is not a built-in library. The URL I linked will explain how to do this.

```
>>> import requests
>>> d = requests.get("http://www.google.ca")
>>> print(d)
<Response [200]>
```

There is a bunch of data you can get from that response. If you do a `d.text`, you will get the text response. I suggest you read the doc to understand how to use it. It is a fully featured library with tons of features.

I suggest looking through the docs for all the other stuff you want.

Comment: yes I did that but I was expecting the results more like {"Number of IOcores": 1, "IOcores": {"iocore0": {"Empty-Loops": "0", "Poll-Cycles": "0", "CPU-frequency": "2099917000", "Poll-Loops": "0", "Number-of-Polled-Interfaces": "0", "Work-Cycles": "4184216", "Spinning-Worker": "YES", "Total-Core-Cycles": "4184216"}}} but I get <Response [200]>

Comment: That is because you are getting back a requests object. This 200 indicates that your call actually worked. You have to now specify what data you want to look at within your object. Did you do a ".text" on your response object? Look at my example carefully. My response object is "d". I specified that you can do a "d.text" as well. Try that.

Comment: Also, from the looks of it you are expecting a json response. So calling the json() method on your object that might work as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
data = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
std_out, std_err = data.communicate()
```

[Docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

The page also contains description about why `shell=True` is dangerous. Worth reading

**EDIT:**

This is the hard way of doing what you want to do. It works so I posted an alternative but I recommend @idjaw answers

Answer (score 0):

Following approach worked for me. It could be usable, if you need to run command with more that one argument:

```
def run_shell_command(cmd, params):
        cmd_list = []
        cmd_list.append(cmd)
        cmd_list + string.split(params)
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        std_out, std_err = p.communicate()
        return std_out, std_err
```

Then, call the function as follows:

```
outp = run_shell_command('curl', '\"URL\" -X GET')
```

P.S: And you [don't](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) need to use `shell=True`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Thank you, fixed